# Trouble passing parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters

For some reason, when I test out my code, my randomly generated numbers don't appear. Here is a sample result:

> What do you want to generate, integer, double, or character?
>
> integer
>
> What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?
>
> 10
>
> 1
>
> How many integers do you want to generate?
>
> 10
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)

Is this because my code is not passing my parameters correctly? I'm not sure how to fix this either.

Here is my code for reference (it's not completed at the moment)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewNumberCharacter {
    /** Main method
     * @param args */
public static void main(String[] args) {
int return_int;
double return_double;
char return_Uchar;
char return_Lchar;
int Min_int;
int Max_int;
double Min_double;
double Max_double;
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Ask the user to enter in the command: integer, double, or character
    System.out.println("What do you want to generate, integer, double, or character?");
    
    // Prompt the user to enter a string, or command, then follow the prompts
    String command = input.nextLine();
    
    if(command.equals("character")){
        System.out.println("How many characters would you like generated?");
    
    int numcharacter = input.nextInt();
    }
    if (command.equals("integer")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?");  
        
    int maxn1 = input.nextInt();
    int minn2 = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to generate?");
    
    int numinteger = input.nextInt();
    }
    if (command.equals("double")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the doubles you want to generate?");
        
    double maxn3 = input.nextDouble();
    double minn4 = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.println("How many doubles do you want to generate?");
    
    int numdouble = input.nextInt();
    }
}
}
// Pass the parameters to a method
public class RandomDataGenerator {
public static int random(int minn2, int maxn1, int numinteger){

    for (int i = 0; i < numinteger; i++){
        System.out.println(maxn1 + (int)(Math.random()* minn2));
}
    return 0;
}
public static double random(double maxn3, double minn4, int numdouble){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numdouble; i++){
       System.out.println(maxn3 + (int)(Math.random() * minn4));
       
    }
    return 0;
}
public static void random(int numcharacter){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numcharacter;  i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

**Update on code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewNumberCharacter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Ask the user to enter in the command: integer, double, or character
    System.out.println("What do you want to generate, integer, double, or character?");
    
    // Prompt the user to enter a string, or command, then follow the prompts
    String command = input.nextLine();
    
    if(command.equals("character")){
        System.out.println("How many characters would you like generated?");
    
    int numcharacter = input.nextInt();
    
    RandomDataGenerator.random(numcharacter);
    }
    if (command.equals("integer")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?");  
        
    int maxn1 = input.nextInt();
    int minn2 = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to generate?");
    int numinteger = input.nextInt();

      RandomDataGenerator.random(minn2,maxn1,numinteger); //Call the method
    }
    if (command.equals("double")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the doubles you want to generate?");
        
    double maxn3 = input.nextDouble();
    double minn4 = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.println("How many doubles do you want to generate?");
    
    int numdouble = input.nextInt();
    
    RandomDataGenerator.random(maxn3,minn4,numdouble);
    }
}
// Pass the parameters to a method
public class RandomDataGenerator {
public static int random(int maxn1, int minn2, int numinteger){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numinteger ; i++ ) {  
        System.out.println(maxn1 + (int)(Math.random()* minn2));    
    }    
    return 0;   
}
public static double random(double maxn3, double minn4, int numdouble){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numdouble; i++){
       System.out.println(maxn3 + (int)(Math.random() * minn4)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
public static void random(int numcharacter){
    for (int i = 0; i < numcharacter;  i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you even calling your random methods??? You call the methods **no-where**, and they're not going to magically work unless you call them first.

Comment: Start by indenting your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the methods that generate random numbers like this:

```
if(command.equals("character")){
    System.out.println("How many characters would you like generated?");
    int numcharacter = input.nextInt();

    RandomDataGenerator.random(numcharacter);//Call the methods
}
else if (command.equals("integer")){
    System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?");  

    int maxn1 = input.nextInt();
    int minn2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to generate?");

    int numinteger = input.nextInt();
    RandomDataGenerator.random(minn2,maxn1,numinteger); //Call the method

}
else if (command.equals("double")){
    System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the doubles you want to generate?");

    double maxn3 = input.nextDouble();
    double minn4 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many doubles do you want to generate?");

    int numdouble = input.nextInt();
    RandomDataGenerator.random(maxn3,minn4,numdouble); //Call the method
}
```

Do note that you haven't completed making the random method which prints random characters.So nothing except new-lines will be printed when you call

```
 RandomDataGenerator.random(numcharacter);
```

Comment: When I input the correction, I get this error message:"Illegal static declaration in inner class NewNumberCharacter.RandomDataGenerator
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations"

Comment: Remove `NewNumberCharacter.` from those lines

Comment: I only see NewNumberCharacter. from the main class. Do I delete that?

Comment: @blue1artic ,How do you call the methods? Is it the **exact** same way as I did?

Comment: I think so, what do you mean?

Comment: I'll have to see your code.The whole thing.Can you edit your question and add it? And don't remove the current code from your question.Just add an "Update:" part and include it.

Comment: @blue1artic ,Remove the last `}` and add `}` just before `public class RandomDataGenerator{`

Comment: "}public class RandomDataGenerator {". I did this, nothing happened.

Comment: @blue1artic ,Try adding a newline between `}` and `public`. Also,did you remove the last `}`?

Comment: Yes I did change it. Can you show me what it would look like?

Comment: @blue1artic , I copied your updated code,added `}` before `public class RandomDataGenerator{` and removed the last `}`. It compiles and runs.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any of your `random` methods (of the `RandomDataGenerator` class) that print the output. That's why you don't see it.

For example, call `RandomDataGenerator.random(minn2, maxn1, numinteger);` to print the randomly generated integers :

```
....
if (command.equals("integer")){
    System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?");  

    int maxn1 = input.nextInt();
    int minn2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to generate?");

    int numinteger = input.nextInt();

    RandomDataGenerator.random(minn2, maxn1, numinteger);
}
....
```